# Capture a specific positional value from a long string using RegEx

Tags: java, regex, parsing

I have a long string that i want to parse and just capture one specific value from a specific position. The string looks like this(specific value in bold):

> {Name: dave,TaskTime: 1503485101000,Log: 5 12345678 test-12345 1.1.1.1
>   2.2.3.3 111 22222 1 **11** 3456 1503485101 1503485102 TEST *CORRECT*,InTime: 1503485105278,Id: 123456789}

The The main problem is, i need find just one regex pattern to capture that value in a group. Would there be any RegEX pattern that can extract that value using a single Regular expression?
Can anyone please provide any suggestions? I tried couple of different ways by searching in stack. I just managed to match some fields using this: `(?:|[=\s])(\w{1,})(?=\s|$)` But that's not enough.

Comment: Are you sure you want to use regexp for a single value? You can just count space symbols and get your value.

Comment: @kotslon yes this is a specific requirements to serve my purpose. i know its not ideal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this regex:

```
(?<=(?:(?:\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3}\s){2}(?:\d+\s){3})(\d+)
```

Explanation:

```
(?<=(?:(?:\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3}\s){2}(?:\d+\s){3})
```

Is positive look behind, designed to find 2 sequential ip addresses followed by 3 numbers:

```
>>1.1.1.1 2.2.3.3 111 22222 1 <<
```

If such pattern is found, the following number is captured. In our case it is 11

Comment: thanks. this helped me to at least somewhat solve the problem. my regex engine didn't allow positive lookbehind though. so i used .*? instead